# How do I remove spaces from phone numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove spaces from phone numbers in a MySQL Database and I used a very simple query to get rid of the spaces using the following case statements:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN TEL_NUMBER like '% %' THEN REPLACE(TEL_NUMBER,' ','') 
        ELSE TEL_NUMBER 
    END AS TEL_NUMBER
FROM
     TEST_TABLE
;
```

but when I started to look through the table I have noticed that in some rows I have 2 numbers showing which are now showing up as long numbers as I removed the spaces like the following:

```
01234567830017431234567
```

So my question is how do I replace the spaces in between 1 phone number as well as trying to replace the space between 2 numbers with either '/' or by even keeping the space between 2 numbers.

Some of the following are examples of the type of scenarios I have:

```
07979871234 01324 456 789
01403123456 01403123587
01747 456789 07813456789
01502 123456 01502 456789
```

Would appreciate it if somebody could advise on how I could fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    concat(substring(replace(TEL_NUMBER, ' ', ''), 1, 11) ,' ', substring(replace(TEL_NUMBER, ' ', ''), 12, 11)) AS TEL_NUMBER
FROM
     TEST_TABLE
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    concat(substring(replace(TEL_NUMBER, ' ', ''), 1, 11) ,'/', substring(replace(TEL_NUMBER, ' ', ''), 12, 11)) AS TEL_NUMBER
FROM
     TEST_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the spaces and put one back in at position 12

```
INSERT(REPLACE(number, ' ', ''), 12, 0, ' ')
```

This INSERT means "in this string eg 01234567830017431234567", at position 12, delete 0 characters, then insert a space -> 01234567830 017431234567

If you want a slash instead, change the string you insert

Beware that phone numbers might not always be 11 digits long.. I have to work with UK phone numbers in one of our systems and the exceptions are a bit of a nuisance.

You might be best off looking for the index of the space that is after the shortest your phone number might be, or the shortest that the longest phone number might be with its spaces (i.e. start the search at position 9 or 10) and insert your slash, then remove all the spaces

```
REPLACE(INSERT(number, LOCATE(number, ' ', 9), 0, '/'), ' ', '')
```

Have a play and fine tune for all your data; you can always update a subset if you find it goes wonky

Comment: Thank you so much both of you, will give that a go and come back to you.

Comment: Thank you both, very useful answers as they both worked and gave me what i wanted.